# Left top Justify text to floated image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to figure out how to have a grid element in a fluid container where there is a `float: left` image with text aligned to the top right side of the image.  I have developed the following bootply to provide a reproducible example:

[Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/UUg3OgHDSv)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="page-content" class="application-body-home">
<h1>Heading</h1>
<div id="intro" class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <p align="left">
    <img style:float:="" left;="" src="http://tmacfitness.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Beauty-of-nature-random-4884759-1280-800.jpg" height="200" width"auto"="">
   Nullam cursus varius tellus, id laoreet magna hendrerit at. Nulla sit amet purus at nunc blandit ultricies eu a urna. Proin euismod porttitor neque id ultricies. Aenean sed turpis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec sem eros, ornare ut, commodo eu, tempor nec, risus. Donec laoreet dapibus ligula. Praesent orci leo, bibendum nec, 
  </p>
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row-fluid">

  <div id:"col1" class="col-md-4"><div class="col-inside">column1</div></div>
  <div id:"col1" class="col-md-4"><div class="col-inside">column2</div></div>
  <div id:"col1" class="col-md-4"><div class="col-inside">column3</div></div>


</div>
</div>
```

In the example there is a random image i found on the internet with the paragraph beginning on right center of the left floated image.

Thanks

Comment: use vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block;

Comment: And always post the code in the question itself.

Comment: is this id assigning? id:"col1"=""

Comment: That's not even what my question is about.

Comment: Though keeping clean and perfect will be answer postable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image says

```
<img style:float:="" left;=""
```

where it should say

```
 <img style="float: left;"
```

Does that answer your question or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Not quite. I am having trouble getting the text to align to the top right of the left floated image.